# Relative clause and Participle

Tags: phrases, relative-clauses

1. Father bought a car which is BMW.

Is it right to say:

—> Father bought a BMW car

2. The apples that are lying on the table are bad.

Are these correct grammatically:

—> the apples lying on the table are bad.
—> the lying apples are on the table.

Comment: "Father bought a car which is BMW" is not ungrammatical, but would not normally be said by a native speaker. "Father bought a BMW" is idiomatic. //  "The apples lying on the table are bad" is fine if a little starchy / highfalutin / contrived (idiomatic is  "The apples on the table are bad"). "The lying apples are on the table" is awful; 'lying' used before a noun almost always means 'telling lies'.

Comment: _One-word modifers_ go **before** the noun they modify (hyphens make multiple words into one-word). _Modifiers of more than one word_ go **after** the word they modify. This is sometimes known as the Eleven-Year-Old Boy rule: both _an eleven-year-old boy_ and _a boy eleven years old_ are grammatical. In the example, _lying on the table_ is a modifier of more than one word and therefore can't be separated and moved to the front.

Answer (score -1):

'Father bought a BMW' is the most natural way to express this, unless you want to contrast with some other mode of transport produced by BMW, such as in

'Father bought a BMW car (, and not a BMW moto).'

The other expressions are fine, except

> The lying apples are on the table

sounds funny because my first reaction to this sentence is that you are saying that the apples are liars, because 'lying' is the ing form of 'to lie', which means both to recline and to tell a lie (fib, untruth). To avoid this, stick with 'the apples are lying on the table'.